# working on angular SSR and my meta tags are not updating when i view source code

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am working with ng universal for SEO implementation

updating meta tags using

```
this.meta.updateTag({ content: value }, `property="${key}"`);
```

and tried with

> this.meta.updateTag({ property: key, content: value });

Meta tags are updating in elements tab but not in

Comment: Any error in the console  server side?

Comment: No i didn't get any error title is updating on the view source but not the meta tags

Comment: same thing happen to me with Angular 10. meta tags updated in Element but not in view source